# Ruby - Send message to a Websocket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket, eventmachine

**How can I send data to a WebSocket using Ruby in a Background Process?**

***Background***

I already have a separate ruby file running a Websocket server using the [`websocket-eventmachine-server`](https://github.com/imanel/websocket-eventmachine-server) gem. However, within my Rails application, I want to send data to the websocket in a background task.

Here is my WebSocket server:

```
EM.run do
  trap('TERM') { stop }
  trap('INT') { stop }

  WebSocket::EventMachine::Server.start(host: options[:host], port: options[:port]) do |ws|

    ws.onopen do
      puts 'Client connected'
    end

    ws.onmessage do |msg, type|
      ws.send msg, type: type
    end

    ws.onclose do
      puts 'Client disconnected'
    end

  end

  def stop
    puts 'Terminating WebSocket Server'
    EventMachine.stop
  end
end
```

However, in my background process (I'm using Sidekiq), I'm not sure how to connect to the WebSocket and send data to it.

Here's my Sidekiq worker:

```
class MyWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(command)
    100.times do |i|
      # Send 'I am on #{i}' to the Websocket
    end  
  end

end
```

I was hoping to be able to do something like `EventMachine::WebSocket.send 'My message!'` but I don't see an API for that or something similar. **What is the correct way to send data to a WebSocket in Ruby?**

Comment: What background job framework are you using?

Comment: Sidekiq, I wasn't sure if that was relevant or not. But good question. :)

Comment: I also did same kind of task but I was using `faye`. I was trying to ping my faye server from within my Ruby Model to push changes to subscribed clients. And this was not working fine because I was unable to move forward unless `faye`'s processing was done and I also don't want to use Background Jobs etc. so I wrapped up my code in a `Thread` instance and everything start working fine. I was using Ruby's standard `net/http` library to send data to `faye`.

Comment: I wouldn't mind using `net/http` to send data to my websocket server, but I'm not sure how to tell EventMachine to accept HTTP requests. Might have to look into that if no one has a solution for me. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I've updated my question since it has been voted as not a real question. If you do not understand something, please ask me as others have done.

Comment: Sidekiq runs on a different process and cannot access the Websocket - so it can't send messages directly through the websocket. You will need Sidekiq to publish to a Redis (or similar) Pub/Sub and have the relevant socket subscribed to the channel.

Answer (score 3):

**Accepted Answer**:

Af your keeping your current websocket server:

You can use [Iodine](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine) as a simple websocket client for testing. It runs background tasks using it's own reactor pattern based code and has a websocket client (I'm biased, I'm the author).

You could do something like this:

```
require 'iodine/http'
Iodine.protocol = :timers
# force Iodine to start immediately
Iodine.force_start!

options = {}
options[:on_message] = Proc.new {|data| puts data}

100.times do |i|
    options[:on_open] = Proc.new {write "I am number #{i}"}
    Iodine.run do
        Iodine::Http.ws_connect('ws://localhost:3000', options) 
    end
end
```

P.S.

I would recommend using a framework, such as [Plezi](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi), for your websockets (I'm the author). Some frameworks let you run their code within a Rails/Sinatra app (Plezi does that and I think Faye, although not strictly a framework, does that too).

Using EM directly is quite hardcore and there are a lot of things to manage when dealing with Websockets, which a good framework helps you manage.

**EDIT 3**:

Iodine WebSocket client connections are (re)supported starting with Iodine 0.7.17, including TLS connections when OpenSSL `>= 1.1.0`.

The following code is an updated version of the original answer:

```
require 'iodine'

class MyClient
  def on_open connection
    connection.subscribe :updates
    puts "Connected"
  end
  def on_message connection, data
    puts data
  end
  def on_close connection
    # auto-reconnect after 250ms.
    puts "Connection lost, re-connecting in 250ms"
    Iodine.run_after(250) { MyClient.connect }
  end

  def self.connect
    Iodine.connect(url: "ws://localhost:3000/path", handler: MyClient.new)
  end
end


Iodine.threads = 1
Iodine.defer { MyClient.connect if Iodine.master? }
Thread.new { Iodine.start }

100.times {|i| Iodine.publish :updates, "I am number #{i}" }
```

**EDIT 2**:

<strike>This answer in now outdated, since Iodine 0.2.x doesn't include a client any longer. Use Iodine 0.1.x or a different gem for websocket clients</strike>.

Answer (score 1):

`websocket-eventmachine-server` is a websockets **server**.

If you want to connect to a websocket server using ruby, you can do it with some gems, like

- [`https://github.com/igrigorik/em-websocket`](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-websocket): Both server and client, also based on eventmachine.
- [`ruby-websocket-client`](https://github.com/mplatov/ruby-websocket-client): Client only

Comment: Thanks, What I've done is setup a websockets **server** with the goal in mind of having the browser and the Rails application connect to it. I was hoping for the Rails app to send messages to the server, and then the browser would automatically pick up on those messages through the JS WebSocket connection. I've looked at `em-websocket` but wasn't sure how to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @ardavis If the browser will pickup the messages, why are you using websocket instead a periodic javascript running on the browser? One good thing from websockets is that, once opened, the communication is bidirectional, thus your websocket application can send information anytime to the browser.

Comment: `WebSockets` Server should be accessible in the form of "ws://example.com". How are you connecting your Clients to `WebSockets` Server?

Comment: In the browser I have a websocket connection with `connection = new WebSocket('ws://my-uri')` and it connects successfully. I also have an `onmessage` function so that whenever it receives a message, it appends it to a `<div>` on the page. I may be over-complicating things accidentally. My Rails application is processing data in a Sidekiq background Worker, and I want to post a message to the websocket in a loop that the browser's JS will pickup on. Does this make more sense? I'm very new to websockets and have a lot to learn :)

Comment: @ardavis: I think you should try using `net/http` to send request to your `ws://example.com` programmatically. If you can ping to your `WebSockets` Server successfully then it will be quite easy to do anywhere. Please! try it first in a stand-alone Ruby file with `WebSockets` Server running.